# How to get all active IP address available on the network?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, ip-address

In this code find only system IP address and system name and I want to find all IP addresses and names available on network.

```
String StringHost;

StringHost = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

IPHostEntry ipEntry =System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(StringHost);

IPAddress[] address = ipEntry.AddressList;

for (int i = 1; i < address.Length; i++)
{

    IP_Address_Datagridview.Rows.Add();
    IP_Address_Datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = StringHost;
    IP_Address_Datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = address[i].ToString();

}
```

Comment: You mean you want to find other computers on the network?

Comment: what do you mean "I want to find all IP addresses and names available on network." ?

Comment: Angry IP Scanner is a utility I have used in the pass for these kind of searches. There source is available on Github which will likely help you: https://angryip.org/

Comment: You can use `nmap` for that, for exmaple, and look at its output

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to see if a computer is on a local network is to use ICMP to 'ping' each address on your subnet.  If the ICMP service is enabled on the IP address you are trying, (which is usually is on workstations, but not always on servers), then you will get a response.

Then you will want to take each valid IP address and do a reverse namespace lookup.

Comment: Syed: If you find you have nodes that have ICMP deactivated, you may want to probe for open well-known ports.

Comment: ICMP is not active always. That's why nmap comes handy it test sending a different packets with flags making the host send some kind of response. Never trust ICMP to perform this task.